# Hard disk making a sound and not working

Tags: external-hard-drive

Good day,
I was trying to connect my external hard drive to my computer yesterday but I found out that it was not spinning like it used to (the spinning was slow) and I was hearing a sound like a click at intervals and my computer will not detect the hard drive.
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You buy a new hard drive, and restore your backups.

The *best* case scenario is you're not getting enough power. Try a Y cable or a usb port directly on a motherboard.

If the USB -> sata  controller board is shot, it won't get detected at all, You MIGHT be able to extract the drive and test the drive. Many 2.5 inch drives are integrated

[If its a head crash it might click like that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_of_death#Hard_disk_drives) this is the worst case scenario and there's pretty much nothing that would ensure the data on the drive is recoverable.

Answer (score 0):

This could be two things:

- Your harddrive may be broken
- you do not provide enough power. Try a Y-Cable with 2 USB plugs (if it's a USB-powered drive) or check the power supply (if it's an externally powered drive).